# Making call from iphone application without exiting it from ios sdk4.0

Tags: ios4, call, ios-4.2

i want to know whether their is any way in ios 4.0 and onwards to make a call from application without exiting the application.

I have worked on this and got to know that their is not any way till iOS 3.1. So I want to know is iOS 4 supports it or not. Need Some other solution than that of

UIApplication application] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8005551212"]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt://8005551212"]];
```

for iOS 4.x it works.

Comment: I am using same but it exits app. We have to reopen it. As iphone 4 supports multitasking App starts from the point where it exits.